# Are there any accounts from crew of sunken submarines?

Tags: submarine

Are there any accounts (written or in other forms) from sunken submarines where the crew was unable to escape? The only ones I am aware of are notes written by the crew of the Kursk after it sank, the contents of which do not seem to have been released in full and which probably do little more than outline the situation and list of survivors anyway.

Many submarines have been recovered after sinking and returned to service, or examined to learn more about the accident. Have any accounts by the crew been recovered and published?

Comment: As a rule, if a submarine is doomed and the crew unable to escape, **there are no survivors.** What are you talking about?

Comment: In the example I cited of the Kursk, although the crew died they were able to write notes before perishing which were later recovered when the submarine was raised.

Comment: They may have written notes, but none of them survived. There were no survivors.

Comment: Are you asking if there are information given by writing or any other means by member of a crew of a sunk submarine?

Comment: @Viralk yes. As I explained, there has been at least once instance of a note written by a crew member who subsequently died being retrieved later from the wreck. The case of the Kursk written notes were recovered, and in other instances things like code books have been retrieved.

Comment: @user ok now I understand, but if someone dies in a sunken submarine he can't be a survivor :) I edit the question to be more clear

Comment: Too broad. How would one prove the nonexistence?

Comment: Question probably spurred by this song : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZaLk-LqR0pc